# Why doesn't ./configure work in python setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools, automake

When using `subprocess.call(["./configure"])` and then `subprocess.call(["make"])` in a python `setup.py` file, why might autotools look for the wrong version of automake? We are calling:

```
$ python setup.py install
....
WARNING: 'automake-1.13' is missing on your system.

     You should only need it if you modified 'Makefile.am' or

     'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.

     The 'automake' program is part of the GNU Automake package:

     <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>

     It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:

     <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>

     <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>

     <http://www.perl.org/>
```

Comment: what about a piece of code to show, what is failing? Show the code, provide complete error trace, explain, what "does not work" means.

Comment: My first guess would be that setup.py filters or mangles environment variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: turn `AM_MAINTAINER_MODE` off with `--disable-maintainer-mode`.

Long answer: Despite the version difference, it should not error out since it works fine on the command line. Something with the Python packaging process is interfering.

When you do

```
$ python setup.py sdist
```

the `setuptools` module creates hard links, makes a tar archive from that, then deletes the hard links. During this linking process, the timestamps on the files have been modified and don't match the original modification times, creating the illusion that some of the source files have been modified.

When the Makefile is run, it notices the timestamp difference. If `AM_MAINTAINER_MODE` is enabled, it runs the `missing` script. This script then detects the difference in versions of aclocal, causing `make` to error out.

Passing the `--disable-maintainer-mode` option to the configure script should suppress the invocation of the `missing` script and allow the build to succeed:

```
subprocess.call(["./configure", "--disable-maintainer-mode"])
subprocess.call(["make"])
```

(See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/maintainer_002dmode.html) for more information about automake's maintainer mode. Apparently the timestamp business is also a problem with users of CVS.)